How to use different "with" under "if" statement in python?
The source code is like:
with A:
    do_some()

I want to choose differenct with statement base on if conditions like the code below. And the do_some() is still under with statement.
if cond1:
    with A:
else:
    with B:
do_some() 

How should I do that?

what objects are your As and Bs? could you give us more context?

Do you agree that the second code box somehow contradicts its description? This also doesn't compile in Python. Wouldn't it be better to write two do_some()s in the appropriate place and ask for options to reduce the code duplication?

You can save the object which will be used as context manager as a variable, before using it in a with statement.
if cond1:
    context = A
else:
    context = B

with context:
    do_some()

Or, using a conditional expression, you can select the context manager directly on the with line:
with A if cond1 else B:
    do_some()


@user2357112 Is there a fundamental difference between the two ways?

Nope, just readability/personal preference.

Something like this is possible as commented by jsharpe:
def structural_playground(cond):
    with open("out1.txt", "w") if cond else open("out2.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello world!")

But the way that I'd prefer because more obvious was already shown by mkrieger1.
